# php postgresql connection

Tags: php, postgresql

i couldnt solve the above below error.. somebody please help me..

when i was trying to connect with postgresql using pg_connect(), it says that "Fatal error.. call to undefined function pg_connect..".

please help me....

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to uncomment (remove the first `;`) the PostgreSQL extension in your `php.ini`:

> **php_pgsql.dll** - if you're on Windows

---

> **pgsql.so** - if you're on *nix

Answer (score 0):

You can also connect to a database using PDO.